# $\text{arg}(i \: \text{conj}(z))=\text{arg}(i)+\text{arg}(\text{conj}(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a Complex Analysis question.

Let z be a complex number, i be the imaginary unit, arg be the argument of z, and $\bar{z}$be the complex conjugate of z.

How do I prove that the following equality holds?

$\text{arg}(i \: \bar{z})=\text{arg}(i)+\text{arg}(\bar{z})$

I haven't been able to prove it using the definition of the argument function together with the trig form of a complex number alone. Please do not prove it using the polar form if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For $z=a+bi$, [use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29#Identities) $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2),\,\mod(-\pi,\pi]$:
$$
\arg(i\overline{z})=\arg(i)+\arg(\overline{z}).
$$

---

To see why the identity is true, note that $z=|z|e^{i\arg z}$, so
$$
\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(|z_1z_2|e^{i(\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2))})=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2),\,\mod (-\pi,\pi].$$

Throughout I am using $\arg$ as the [principal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29#Principal_value), since it seems LaTeX doesn't have $\Arg$ built in (?).

Comment: Right, so now I get it that mine was the particular case of a more general result. Yet that Wikipedia entry does not prove the general case either. Can you please prove it? Thanks

Comment: I edited to add it. Just write the two complex numbers in polar-arg form and multiply.